# Tense agreement in a special case

Tags: tense-agreement

I am not sure especially about the agreement between: "specifies", "would be bought" and "were delivered". In the original non-English version the text is like this: "The agreement **specifies** that the apparatus **will be bought** if two copies **are delivered** before September 1, 1886" but likely it can not stay like this in English.

This is my attempt:

> In 1885, the inventor might have made such an affirmation because the agreement between him and an investor (which I am reading now, February 11, 2017) **specifies** that the apparatus **would be bought** for the sum of $50000 if at least two working copies **were delivered** before September 1, 1886.

The text of the agreement is like this:

> The inventor will receive $50000 if he delivers two working copies of his apparatus before September 1, 1886.

Comment: There are too many changes between the first and second examples. Rewrites should only differ in the specific terms in question, along with why you think they should be changed.

Comment: The second text is exactly what the agreement says. The first text is from an email (which is not in English) send to me by somebody. I am interested in a correct English version of this first text because I have to quote exactly the person that sent the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either **specified** (because that's what it did at the time it was written) or **specifies** (because it still does now).

As for the other points, it is an example of reported speech: in reported speech, the tenses are backshifted. It's complicated a little further by the use of passive mood in your version.

Looking at the original agreement, when quoted, no backshift is required:

> The agreement says "The inventor will receive $50000 if he delivers two working copies of his apparatus before September 1, 1886."

When reported (without quotes) a backshift is required:

> The agreement specifies thet the inventor **would** receive $50000 if he **delivered** two working copies of his apparatus before September 1, 1886."

Switching to passive voice ("the inventor would receive" -> "the apparatus would be bought", "he delivered" -> "two copies of his apparatus were delivered"):

> The agreement specifies thet the be apparatous **would be bought** for $50000 if two working copies of his apparatus **were delivered** before September 1, 1886.

The tense backshifting is required by the translation because it is reported speech. The text could be grammatically correct in active or passive voice: it is your personal choice whether or not to switch to passive voice.